OpenMP Declare Reduction not recognizing combiner function
I'm trying to declare our own reduction via #pragma omp declare reduction however it seems my combiner expression is not recognized. I believe this bug is perhaps a result of the function’s type being obfuscated since declaring the reduction callback normally works as intended; however when the function is being bound (case 2) or is the calling operator of a struct (case 3) we result in the error:
error: '#pragma omp declare reduceFn combiner refers to variable fn which is not 'omp_out' nor 'omp_in'
Originally I thought the bug could have been due to templating and type related issues, but I tried replacing T in the examples below with int and still was unable to build. I tried looking online but wasn't able to find much information regarding my bug.
Also note that due to the nature of my code, the reduction callback needs to be bound.
Case 1 (working example):
#pragma omp declare reduction(  \
        reduceFn :  \
        T: \
        reductionCallback(omp_out, omp_in))  
        initializer(omp_priv = omp_orig)

Case 2 (the bug I'm facing):
auto fn  = std::bind(reductionCallback<T>,_1,_2);

#pragma omp declare reduction(  \
        reduceFn :  \
        T: \
        fn(omp_out, omp_in))  
        initializer(omp_priv = omp_orig)

//tried setting omp_out explicitly
#pragma omp declare reduction(  \
        reduceFn :  \
        T: \
        omp_out=fn(omp_out, omp_in))  
        initializer(omp_priv = omp_orig)

//tried wrapping the bound function in a lambda
#pragma omp declare reduction(  \
        reduceFn :  \
        T: \
        [](decltype(omp_out) & out, decltype(omp_in) & in) {fn(out,in);} (omp_out,omp_in))  
        initializer(omp_priv = omp_orig)

//still get this error for all 3
error: '#pragma omp declare reduceFn combiner refers to variable fn which is not 'omp_out' nor 'omp_in'

Case 3 (another failing case):
Struct F {
   template < typename T>
   T
   operator () (const T &omp_out, const T &omp_in)
   {
    return omp_out;
    
   };
};
…
F fn;
#pragma omp declare reduction(  \
        reduceFn :  \
        T: \
        fn(omp_out, omp_in))  
        initializer(omp_priv = omp_orig)

error: '#pragma omp declare reduceFn combiner refers to variable fn which is not 'omp_out' nor 'omp_in'


Reduction declarations don't seem to capture variables. You have to include your callback into the reduced type. That can be as simple as replacing T with std::pair<T, reductionCallback<T>> or embedding T in your struct F but of course then the whole thing also needs to be copyable etc. So a specific answer requires more details of your use case, like what is bound?
